# Powershell - Assign Each Day a Variable

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script that assigns a variable to 'yesterday', uses a RestAPI to grab my locations' sunrise and sunset times based on yesterday's date, and then formats the results.

```
$yesDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497&formatted=0&date=$yesDate").results
$sunrise  = ($daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$sunset   = ($daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

What I now want to do is update the script to take each day of the month (for instance, Sept 1 through 27 (yesterday)), grab the sunrise and sunset values, and then assign them a variable (for instance `$sunrise1` and `$sunset1`).

Any idea on how I could even do this?

UPDATE:

I have an input file with a line for each minute of the day, with a few sample lines below:

2020-09-28 00:00:00 0.0

2020-09-28 00:01:00 0.0

2020-09-28 00:02:00 0.0

2020-09-28 00:03:00 0.0

2020-09-28 00:04:00 0.0

2020-09-28 00:05:00 0.0

I used my original script above to grab yesterdays' sunrise/sunset times, and then used the below script to remove all rows before sunrise and after sunset.  It then, removed the timestamp altogether, then took an average of the remaining values, and finally formatted the average.

```
Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_unedited.txt | 
    Where-Object { $_ -ge $sunrise -and $_ -le $sunset } | 
        Out-File C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_consolidated.txt
(Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_consolidated.txt) -Replace '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\t', '' | 
    Out-File C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_no_timestamp.txt
Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_no_timestamp.txt | 
    Measure-Object -Average | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average |
            Out-File C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_raw_avg.txt
$result = Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_raw_avg.txt
[MATH]::Round($result,1) |
    Out-File C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv.txt
```

This may not be the cleanest way to accomplish the goal, but for the purposes of grabbing an environmental variable on a single day, filtering out the non-daylight hours, and getting the average, it works just fine.  However, the next goal is to perform this same function over a month (and at some point, a year), but taking into account that the sunrise and sunset times change daily...

Comment: Do you really need separate variables? It would seem that an _array_ is the better solution.

Comment: Or a hash table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a different approach and output an array of custom objects with `Sunrise` and `Sunset` properties.

```
# Yesterday
$yesdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

# Loop through day 1 to yesterday
$Times = 1..$yesdate.Day | Foreach-Object {
    $currentDate = Get-Date -Day $_ -Month $yesdate.Month -Year $yesdate.Year -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    $daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497&formatted=0&date=$currentDate").results
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Sunrise = ([datetime]$daylight.Sunrise).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        Sunset = ([datetime]$daylight.Sunset).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    }
}
# Outputs sample section

# $Times is an array of objects with sunrise and sunset properties
# $Times one array element for each day starting from day 1 to yesterday of the given month
$Times 
# Outputs day 1 sunrise
$Times[0].Sunrise
# Outputs day 10 sunset
$Times[9].Sunset
# Outputs day 15 sunrise and sunset as an object
$Times[14]
# Outputs day 15 sunrise and sunset as comma-separated values
"{0},{1}" -f $Times[14].Sunrise,$Times[14].Sunset
```

EDIT: Using your examples

If you want to check a specific day against your file, you can do the following:

```
# Checking day 28

Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_unedited.txt | Where {
    [datetime]($_ -replace '\d+\.\d+') -ge [datetime]$Times[27].Sunrise -and [datetime]($_ -replace '\d+\.\d+') -le [datetime]$Times[27].Sunset
}
```

You could also loop through all the days of the given month:

```
$daily = Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\Txt_Files\daily_values_uv_unedited.txt
foreach ($Time in $Times) {
    $Sunset = [datetime]$Time.Sunset
    $Sunrise = [datetime]$Time.Sunrise
    $daily | Where {
        [datetime]($_ -replace '\d+\.\d+') -ge $Sunrise -and [datetime]($_ -replace '\d+\.\d+') -le $Sunset
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work for what I am looking for.  But, I have a script that (currently) pulls an environmental variable for every minute of every day for the entire month.  What I am trying to get this script to do is to filter out all of the values that did not occur between sunrise and sunset on the given day.  I can easily update my script to pull the env var for each day individually, as opposed to the entire month in on return, but how do I apply your answer to that?

Comment: @sbagnato, I added an update to show you how you can use the array.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  So, I took your first answer and then the updated answer to loop through the days of the month.  It seems to have worked, partially.  It just returns yesterday's values, but nothing for the 1st to the 4th.  Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the dates you want (for all days of a specific month you can use `[DateTime]::DaysInMonth()`. And then use `New-Variable` with the `-Name` paramter to create a dedicated variable for each days - if that's what's needed.

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt [DateTime]::DaysInMonth(2020, 9); $i++) { 
    # $sunrise = your stuff here
    New-Variable -Name sunrise$i -Value $sunrise
}
```

Comment: To select the current month, could I then just assign the current month digit as a variable and then put that in place of "9"?

Comment: Yes, the second argument of DaysInMonth is the month (9 = september)